# Как настроить что бы по умолчанию на сервере использовался PHP8.1

Tags: php, linux, консоль, веб-сервер

подскажите пошаговую инструкцию хотя бы в общих чертах, какие нужно выполнить действия что бы на сервере по умолчанию использовался PHP8.1 вместо PHP7.1.33?
Обе версии интерпритаторов присутствуют в /etc но в консоли если я выполняю

$ php -v

мне выводится так:

> PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: May 24 2022 18:34:03) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
> with the ionCube PHP Loader + ionCube24 v11.0.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by ionCube Ltd.
> with Zend OPcache v7.1.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
> with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans

На другом сервере вот так

> [bitrix@dev ~]$ php -v
> PHP 8.1.22 (cli) (built: Aug  1 2023 16:16:09) (NTS gcc x86_64)
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v4.1.22, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.1.22, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Вот как сделать что бы и на первом сервере было как и на втором, т.е по умолчанию использовалась нужная мне версия PHP?

(особых знаний в конфигурациях серверов нет, ставил только php и percona с nginx, так что исходите из того некоторые очевидные вещи для меня могут быть не известны...)

Comment: Установить php 8.1?

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config php` и выбирайте версию, которую хотите использовать